# First input is not working and the second one will not align with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

In my code, the folder selection is working and the second input in also working, but I can't make the first input to work or to align the second one with the folder selection. I only need one input filed that I can use further to display the input items.

```
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog, simpledialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("400x200")
gui.title("Test")
status = Label(gui, text="", relief=FLAT)
status.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)
frame = Frame(gui)

class FolderSelect(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,folderDescription="",**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=parent,**kw)
        self.folderPath = StringVar()
        self.lblName = Label(self, text=folderDescription)
        self.lblName.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entPath = Entry(self, textvariable=self.folderPath)
        self.entPath.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.btnFind = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse Folder",command=self.setFolderPath)
        self.btnFind.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.lblName2 = Label(self, text="Input")
        self.lblName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
        
        self.directory2Select = StringVar()
        self.entExt = Entry(self, textvariable=self.directory2Select)
        self.entExt.grid(row=1,column=1)


        
    def setFolderPath(self):
        folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.folderPath.set(folder_selected)
    @property
    def folder_path(self):
        return self.folderPath.get()
def popup_showinfo():
    showinfo("Done")
    
def doStuff():
    Images1 = directory1Select.folder_path
    Images2 = directory2Select.get()

    status = Label(gui, text="The folder you selected is " + str(Images1), bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
    status.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)
    status.update()
    print(str(Images2))
    popup_showinfo()

    ##############################################################

    mp = str(Images2)


    def stringToList(string):
        listRes = list(string.split(","))
        return listRes

    strA = mp
    print(stringToList(strA))
    mp = stringToList(strA)
    mp = [x.strip(' ') for x in mp]


    for m in mp:
        print("1 " + m)
    ##############################################################


folderPath = StringVar()

directory1Select = FolderSelect(gui,"Source folder    ")
directory1Select.grid(row=0,column=0)

tk.Label(gui, text="Input").grid(row=1, column = 0)

directory2Select = StringVar()
directory2Select = Entry(gui)
directory2Select.grid(row=1, column=1)




c = ttk.Button(gui, text="Start", command=doStuff)
c.grid(row=4,column=0)
frame.pack()
```

I tried to modify the grid but didn't work. Also tried to pack the frame, but without any result. I could delete the first input and use the second one since I need only one, but I can't figure out how to align it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not `frame.pack()` but `gui.mainloop()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Changed from frame.pack() to gui.mainloop() and still the first input isn't working and the second one is not aligned

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't make the first input to work or to align the second one
> with the folder selection.

> I tried to modify the grid but didn't work. Also tried to pack the
> frame, but without any result.

You had this:

[image]

The problem can be fix.

- Moved `tk.Label(gui` to inside `def __init__`. And  renamed  `self.lbl2 = Label(self, ...`. Change `gui` to `self`.
- Move `directory2Select = Entry(gui)` and
  `directory2Select.grid(row=1, column=1)` to inside `def __init__`. And
  renamed `self.directory2Select`. And `gui` to `self`.
- I leave that directory2Select = StringVar() to comment out or in,
  because of duplicate. It is up to you to re-name.
- Change `frame.grid()` to `frame.pack()`, which already has slaves
  managed by grid.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog, simpledialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("400x200")
gui.title("Test")
status = Label(gui, text="", relief=FLAT)
status.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)
frame = Frame(gui)

class FolderSelect(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,folderDescription="",**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=parent,**kw)
        self.folderPath = StringVar()
        self.lblName = Label(self, text=folderDescription)
        self.lblName.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entPath = Entry(self, textvariable=self.folderPath)
        self.entPath.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.btnFind = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse Folder",command=self.setFolderPath)
        self.btnFind.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.lblName2 = Label(self, text="Input" )
        self.lblName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
        
        self.directory2Select = StringVar()
        self.entExt = Entry(self, textvariable=self.directory2Select)
        self.entExt.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.lbl2 = Label(self, text="Input")
        self.lbl2.grid(row=2, column = 0)
        self.directory2Select = Entry(self)
        self.directory2Select.grid(row=2, column=1)
         
        
    def setFolderPath(self):
        folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.folderPath.set(folder_selected)
        
    @property
    def folder_path(self):
        return self.folderPath.get()
    
def popup_showinfo():
    showinfo("Done")
    
def doStuff():
    Images1 = directory1Select.folder_path
    Images2 = directory2Select.get()

    status = Label(gui, text="The folder you selected is " + str(Images1), bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
    status.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)
    status.update()
    print(str(Images2))
    popup_showinfo()

    ##############################################################

    mp = str(Images2)

    def stringToList(string):
        listRes = list(string.split(","))
        return listRes

    strA = mp
    print(stringToList(strA))
    mp = stringToList(strA)
    mp = [x.strip(' ') for x in mp]


    for m in mp:
        print("1 " + m)
    ##############################################################


folderPath = StringVar()

directory1Select = FolderSelect(gui,"Source folder    ")
directory1Select.grid(row=0,column=0)
 
#directory2Select = StringVar()
 

c = ttk.Button(gui, text="Start", command=doStuff)
c.grid(row=4,column=0)
frame.grid()
           

gui.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]